# How to add a halo to a text in the composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I would like to add texts with halo, in the composer (not in the map). Do you know a way to do it?

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add a new label in `QGIS 2.0.1 Composer`.

In the `item properties` if you put the following code

```html
<span style="color:blue;text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #4d2d4d, 0px 5px 10px #aefe00;">Test</span>
```

you'll obtain the desired effect:

[image]

(Don't forget to disable the `item background` if you are looking for a *transparent* label!)

---

**EDIT**

Some `text-shadow` explanations below:

[image]

For offsets and blur you can use positive or negative values.

---

More, you can have multiple shadows, like this:

*Example 1:*

```html
<span style="color:brown;text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px #fff, 0.7px 0.7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Test</span>
```

And you'll see this:

[image]

*Example 2:*

```html
<span style="color:violet;text-shadow: -0.5px 0.5px 0px #00e6e6, -1px 1px 0px #01cccc, -1.5px 1.5px 0px #00bdbd;">Test</span>
```

[image]

*Example 3:*

```html
<span style="color:white;text-shadow:
               0 1px 0 #ccc, 
               0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
               0 3px 0 #bbb,
               0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
               0 5px 0 #aaa,
               0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
               0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
               0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);">Test</span>
```

[image]

Comment: It is the first time I use HTML, you just introduced me to a new world! Exploring your suggestion, I found that code, corresponding exactly to what I was searching for: "text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white". Thanks a lot

Comment: I am trying to use a specific font for the label, can you specify how I achieve this? A quick search hasn´t helped so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Another, easy way to achieve the same as the buffer function in QGIS.DESKTOP is the following:

```html
<p style="-webkit-text-stroke: 3px white">Test</p>
```

[image]