# How to add a halo to a dynamic label of an attribute in Atlas?

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

How can I apply this for a dynamic label of an attribute in atlas? I'm using QGIS 2.18.10

[How to add a halo to a text in the composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84324/how-to-add-a-halo-to-a-text-in-the-composer/254618#254618)

Answer (score 1):

Using the method provided in the [mentionned answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84324/how-to-add-a-halo-to-a-text-in-the-composer/254618#254618), you can replace the static text by an expression. Make sure to enclose it between `[% %]` and use the variable name (starting with `@`). If you click on the `expression` button, you can access all the list of available variables.

Let's note that the mix of an expression and the html label, together, are not a valid expression.

```
<span style="color:blue;text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #4d2d4d, 0px 5px 10px #aefe00;"> 
   [% @qgis_version %] 
</span>
```

[image: Atlas label halo]